# Socket.io emit in app doesn't work

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I emit "wallet-update" with data but io doesn't react on it:

```
io.emit("wallet-update", total);
io.on('wallet-update', function(data){
     console.log(data);
});
```

And when I emit events from socket in browser all is ok:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('connect', function()  {
        console.log("connect");
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean doesn't react on it?

Comment: The server does not respond to the event

Comment: when you use `io.emit` , server should not respond to it. you are emitting a message from server to all clients. your clients should receive "wallet-update" event with given data not your server.

Comment: Aahhahahah of course, I am soooo stupid, thank you a lot! :-)